# Currency-related fields not in Dynamics CRM 4.0 entity export

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have an installation of Dynamics CRM 4.0 that consists of two environments: one for development and one for production. We have an entity (a custom one) that contains currency-related attributes (currency and exchange rate) in the production environment, but the same entity in development does not have those same attributes.

We attempted to sync these entities up by exporting the customizations for that entity from production and applying them to development, but those two currency-related attributes do not appear in the exported schema data (customizations.xml).

Is there something about the currency lookup and the exchange rate attribute that prevent them from being exported?

---

**Update and more details:**

The CRM installation has been updated to the latest rollup (21) with no effect.

The attributes make sense in the context of the entity (it represents a country), but to my knowledge, these two fields are not being used. The entity was added to our system as part of a vendor customization. We are simply trying to keep our development environment synced with production, and we are stumped as to why these two fields will not export.

The entity has no money attributes.

Comment: Is there anything to be discovered by exporting all customizations?

Comment: Does the entity contain money fields?

Comment: @klugerama: No. After exporting all customizations, the XML definition for the entity in question still does not contain the exchangerate or transactioncurrencyid attributes.

Comment: @ccellar: No, no money fields.

Answer (score 1):

Do these attributes show up when you explore the metadata on the production system, i.e. by using the list.aspx. In other words: have these two attributes been added to the system in a supported way?

Comment: Yes, they do appear on the /sdk/list.aspx page.

Comment: And did you publish the customizations for this entity on production?

Comment: Yes. Just to make sure, I republished the entity in question then exported the customizations again. The two attributes are still missing in the exported data.

Comment: Nasty problem. It looks like PRD is corrupt. Try the following: export the customizations for only this single entity. Import them into your development system. Add the fields that have been omitted by hand. (Do not forget to add them to the form etc.) Publish your customizations and export them from DEV. Try to import the customizations into PRD. There is a chance you get rid of the corrupted customization in your PRD system. NOTE: don't forget to backup your PRD first!